# iOS Simulator installations fail on Xcode 6.4 on El Capitan v10.11

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode-simulator

[image]

> Could not download and install iOS 7.1 Simulator. Authorization is required to install the packages.

Facing this issue on Xcode 7 Beta 6 version too.

Can't seem to understand why?

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 7 does not support iOS 8.4 and earlier.

Xcode 6.4 does not support iOS 7.1.2 and earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Running the following command in Terminal

```
sudo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
```

and then downloading the simulator 7.1 works for me. I'm using Xcode 6.4, OS X El Capitan.

Comment: Can you actually use the 7.1 simulator in El Capitan? Do you have Xcode 7 installed too or only Xcode 6.4? - Thanks

Comment: This makes possible to install it, but I get a message "unable to load" when I try to run the app. So I think it's just not supported